# Warning sprintf() function.sprintf too few arguments

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress script but the menu disappears when the url includes non-latin characters. Example: `www.site.com/بحث`

I Get:

```
warning sprintf() function.sprintf too few arguments in nav-menu-template.php
```

At this line:

```
$nav_menu .= sprintf( $args->items_wrap, esc_attr( $wrap_id ), esc_attr( $wrap_class ), $items );
```

Comment: What are the values to the arguments to `sprintf`

Comment: I also had a similar problemوplease check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58213018/5753091),

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes its a problem if you have arabian characters in your url.

http://istizada.com/understanding-arabic-url-uri-structure-encoding-for-arabic-sites/

This is a cool post what happen when you have such a URL.

But normally this error means, that you have more placeholders as strings to replace. I think when you have such characters in your URL its transformed to UTF-8 URL encoding.

```
%D9%86 = ن
```

Then you have something like this and when you put that directly to your `sprintf` you have some new placeholders and such errors.

Try rawurldecode to change that characters back.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.rawurldecode.php