# Sprintf, too few arguments in wordpress nav-menu-template.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Why I'm getting a Warning after installing wpseo theme from TF.

```
Warning: sprintf() [function.sprintf]: Too few arguments in .../wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php on line 403

$nav_menu .= sprintf( $args->items_wrap, esc_attr( $wrap_id ), esc_attr( $wrap_class ), $items );
```

I am not using url includes non-latin characters, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27468905/warning-sprintf-function-sprintf-too-few-arguments).
Can you help me?